# What proportion of the space is taken up by independent discrete uniform variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, uniform-distribution, coupon-collector-problem

If you take $N$ independent uniform random selections from a discrete space with $M$ possibilities (with replacements), then what proportion of the possibilities will have been selected?

---

Formally, this problem can be stated as follows.  Let $X_1, ..., X_N \sim \text{IID U} \{ 1, ..., M \}$ and let $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \{ 1, ..., M \}$ be the subset of categories having at least one value in this sample.  Find the expected value $\mathbb{E}(|S|/M)$ which is the expected proportion of categories hit by the random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the answer by @Ben, this is not the coupon collector problem, but an associated problem, the *classical occupancy problem*.  See for instance [an interesting blog post](https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-occupancy-problem/) or  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631487/asymptotics-of-the-classical-occupancy-problem

```
Old Answer below:
```

What you have is a version of the famous coupon collectors problem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem  and on this site https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector.  You will find answer to your question there.  There is also a lot of information on the web.

Comment: Although this sounds like the Coupon Collector problem, and clearly is related to it, it is not the same.  The CC problem asks for the distribution of the *random variable* $N$ given by the number of selections required to fill the space completely.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the answer by [kjetil](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen), this is actually the "classical occupancy problem" (which is related to the coupon collector's problem, but is not quite the same problem).  The random variable $|S|$ has a **classical occupancy distribution** with mass function given by:

$$\mathbb{P} \big( |S| = s \big| n, m \big) = \frac{(m)_s \cdot S(n,s)}{m^n} \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 1 \leqslant s \leqslant \min (n,m),$$

where $(m)_s = \prod_{i=0}^{s-1} (m-i)$ are the [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and $S(n,s)$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  The properties of this distribution are well-known (see e.g., Johnson and Kotz 1977).  The expected value of this random variable is:

$$\mathbb{E} \big( |S| \big) = m \Big( 1 - \frac{1}{m}  \Big)^n.$$

Dividing through by the number of categories gives $\mathbb{E} ( |S|/m ) = ( 1 - \tfrac{1}{m}  )^n \rightarrow \exp(-n/m)$, where the latter asymptotic form holds as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

---

Johnson, N.L. and Kotz, S. (1977) *Urn Models and their Applications*. John Wiley and Sons: New York.